# iOS precision differences between debug/release builds messing up views?

Tags: iphone, ios, build

I have some code where I'm trying to modify the attributes of one CGRect, and set another CGRect with this new frame:

```
actView         = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray ] autorelease];
actView.hidesWhenStopped = NO;
[actView startAnimating];
frame           = actView.frame;
frame.origin.x  = mainLabel.frame.origin.x - frame.size.width - TBLCELLPADDING;
frame.origin.y  = mainLabel.frame.origin.y;
actView.tag     = TBLCELLACTTAG;
actView.frame   = frame;
[cell.contentView addSubview:actView];
```

This works fine in debug builds and release builds for newer iPhones.  Running on a release build for a 3G iPhone however, creates some crazy results and messes up the views.

Expected Results (works with newer phones):

```
2012-01-01 14:41:43:449 myapp [691:775] Loading MainLabel: 122.000000 26.000000
2012-01-01 14:41:43:605 myapp[691:775] Loading Frame: 97.000000 26.000000
2012-01-01 14:41:43:713 myapp[691:775] Loading ActView: 97.000000 26.000000
```

Results for an iPhone 3G running 4.2 firmware with a Release Build (this happens on any firmware):

```
2012-01-01 14:43:39:516 myapp[706:775] Loading MainLabel: 122.000000 26.000000
2012-01-01 14:43:39:589 myapp[706:775] Loading Frame: 26.000000 26.000000
2012-01-01 14:43:39:792 myapp[706:775] Loading ActView: 26.000000 0.000000
```

This is screwing up views all across my app for this older iPhone.
Is there a way I should specifically be handling this in terms of code?  Or should I modify something in the build settings for older iPhones?

Comment: Sounds like some kind of race condition.

Comment: Add some sort of sleep call(or spinwait) before the line that sets `frame.origin.x`. If that removes the problem, you have a race condition which you should fix by using appropriate synchronization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the problem only exists on ARMV6 based devices and only when building optimized code, it  possibly is founded in the faulty ARMV6 optimizing of llvm.

Add the following to your build settings as a user defined setting:

```
GCC_THUMB_SUPPORT = NO
```

This is how it should look like:
[image]

What this does is, it entirely disabled the thumb instruction set build for your app. If this results into a properly functioning App, check if the App still performs fine on the ARMV7 devices as this setting may severely influence the performance.

Even though this appears to be a GCC specific setting, this still is respected by LLVM and saved my behind in some older projects that I needed to update.

Comment: This is the correct solution, and has also been fixed in Xcode 4.3 beta.

Comment: @JoshuaWeinberg great to know that Apple finally fixed this, thanks for spreading the word.

Comment: Yes this solved my issue.  So this is fixed in 4.3 and up, supposedly?  Will the fix in newer versions of xcode slow down armv7 compilations?

Answer (score 0):

You could always specify different code settings if the app is running on an older phone. Use precompiler headings.

Comment: If it's a race condition, then it's likely that the bug is there on all phones, but only gets noticed on old ones. In that case hiding the symptoms isn't the right solution.

Comment: What would you suggest though? It seems like the only other option would be living with it...